# Ionic - Playing Audio in background

Tags: android, cordova, audio, ionic-framework

I am creating one music app which will get songs using API. Songs are playing perfectly but its not working in background. When I close the app audio gets stop. I am creating this app with `ionic framework` and using `cordova Media` plugin. I have googled many things but not able to resolve the issue.

Shall I need to use some other plugin instead of `cordova Media`. Please give some suggestion.

*Note: I need only for android devices*

Comment: why this down vote? If I have done some silly/wrong question then intimate me and give me some solution.

Comment: Have you been able to find the answer ? I neutralized down votes coz they are silly. not your question.

Comment: @user3786285 .. Yes I have found 1 solution. Please check my answer below.

Comment: oh i see. hold on let me check later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't get any solution. So I have created one plugin for it. 
Please refer this link [Cordova Plugin - Back As Home](https://github.com/amitsinha559/cordova-plugin-back-as-home)

**What exactly it's doing?**
Instead of closing the app, it's minimizing it. So this code will help back button to work as home button.

**Add Plugin**

cordova plugin add https://github.com/amitsinha559/cordova-plugin-back-as-home.git

**Add this codes in `.run` if you want to work back as home button**

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e){
    backAsHome.trigger(function(){
        console.log("Success");
    }, function(){
        console.log("Error");
    });
    e.preventDefault();
},101);
```

**If you want to use in some button action**

```
$scope.someButton = function() {
    backAsHome.trigger(function(){
        console.log("Success");
    }, function(){
        console.log("Error");
    });
}
```

Please let me know if you are facing any issue.

Comment: I use NativeAudio plugin for my audio application and I use your plugin for background run . but when i click back button application goes minimize but audio pause.  i need to know that are you use cordova  media plugin or NativeAudio plugin. Please help

Comment: Cordova Media Plugin

Comment: Hundreds of developers will have a nice sleep at night because of your efforts. :)

Answer (score 1):

The OS will put the screen and the CPU to sleep unless you acquire a wakelock - Partial wakelock in your case.

There are two attempts to prevent cordova apps from sleeping, or run in the background. Have a look at those plugins.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService

Comment: Thanks I will check it and get back to you :)